# Separate lower level child nodes

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-node

I'm trying to represent a diagram of Max Heapify. I used the following settings for `tikz`

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  heap/.style={
    every node/.style={circle,draw},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=80mm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=50mm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=30mm},
    level 4/.style={sibling distance=20mm}
  }
}
```

For the tikzpicture, I wrote the following

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[heap]
  \node {6}
  child{node{8}
    child{node{9} 
    child{node{13}} child{node{23}}} 
    child{node{7}
        child{node{1}} child{node{5}}}} 
  child{node{5}
    child{node{12}
    child{node{7}} child{node{10}}} 
    child{node{4}
    child{node{4}}}} 
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Apparently two child nodes on the lowest level seem to be merged together in the output

[image]

How can I fix this, so child nodes on the bottom are not merged?

Comment: Just reduce the last level distance. And, not related, but you may want to have all nodes the same size, so use `minimum size` in your `every node` style.

Comment: @SebGlav I've tried that and I get the same output

Comment: See my answer about level distances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root is has no sibbling, so you start counting at level one just under the root. The lowest level of your tree is level 3 here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

        \tikzset{
              heap/.style={
                every node/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=8mm},
                level 1/.style={sibling distance=80mm},
                level 2/.style={sibling distance=50mm},
                level 3/.style={sibling distance=20mm}, % <----- Here's the lowest level of your tree
                level 4/.style={sibling distance=10mm}
              }
            }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[heap]

            
        \node {6}
              child{node{8}
                child{node{9} 
                child{node{13}} child{node{23}}} 
                child{node{7}
                    child{node{1}} child{node{5}}}} 
              child{node{5}
                child{node{12}
                child{node{7}} child{node{10}}} 
                child{node{4}
                child{node{4}}}} 
              ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```